# SAS cannot save graphs to specified destination

Tags: sas

Why can't I save the graphs to specified file as expected? Could someone help me out on this? thanks very much.

Best regards,
Mi

```
%macro Corr(in,out,y,x,separateBy,titleString,xSize=900pt,ySize=600pt,saveDestination="c:\sas graph",saveResolution=400);
goptions reset=all hsize=&xSize vsize=&ySize;
ods graphics on;
ods listing gpath=&saveDestination image_dpi=&saveResolution;
ods graphics / imagename='Repeat' imagefmt=jpeg;

proc reg data=&in outest=&out simple edf;
    title "&titleString of #ByVal(_name_)";/*Double quotation required when macro variable present in title string*/
    model &y=&x / alpha=0.05 noprint;
    id bladeSerialNumber;
    by &separateBy;
    plot &y*&x;
run;

quit;

ods graphics off;
title '';
%mend;

*Invoke Example;
libname ro 'c:\sas output\ro';
%corr(ro.SUMMARY_SPLITBYITERATION_METHOD1,corrSummary,Iter2,Iter1,_name_,Repeatability);
```

Here are the partial notes from SAS:

`%corr(ro.SUMMARY_SPLITBYITERATION_METHOD1,corrSummary,Iter2,Iter1,_name_,Repeatability);`

`WARNING: The variable _NAME_ or _TYPE_ exists in a data set that is not TYPE=CORR, COV, SSCP, etc.`

`NOTE: Graph's name, REG, changed to REG384. REG is already used or not a valid SAS name.`

`NOTE: Graph's name, REG, changed to REG112. REG is already used or not a valid SAS name.`

`NOTE: 29844 bytes written to C:\Users\mzhou7165825\AppData\Local\Temp\SEG8728\SAS Temporary Files\_TD9196_5K82J12A_\Prc2\reg384.png.`

`ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access C:\windows\system32\sasgraph.png`

`NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      NAME OF FORMER VARIABLE=Amplitude10LVGA`

`NOTE: Graph's name, REG, changed to REG385. REG is already used or not a valid SAS name.`

`NOTE: Graph's name, REG, changed to REG113. REG is already used or not a valid SAS name.`

Comment: I've gotten that from EG when I had the output was going to the listing destination. If you close that (either with menus, or perhaps `ODS listing close`) does that help?

Comment: thanks. ODS listing close helps to suppress the error but the graphs do not save to the destination.

Comment: Do you get a warning or error in the log?

Comment: there is only a warning message that WARNING: The variable _NAME_ or _TYPE_ exists in a data set that is not TYPE=CORR, COV, SSCP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all please make sure that the `saveDestination="c:\sas graph"` is pointing to an existing folder and that you assign a filename to the output.

Check:

1. if you are running sas locally, that your user has write access to the folder
2. if you are running sas on server, that the "server user" has write access to the folder.

**Second**, if the **first** sentence evaluates to false (and also sas is running locally) then create the folder with the required user access rights.

However if you are running sas remotely, you won't be able to write to your local computer, but to the server only. In case of windows server, you can use the following syntax to save your file:

[code start]

```
%let mypath = C:\Users\%sysfunc(dequote(&_CLIENTUSERID))\Documents\;
```

this

```
ods pdf file= "&mypath\yourfile.pdf";
```

or this

```
ods listing gpath = "&mypath\yourfile.jpeg";


*** your code***


ods _all_ close;
```

[code end]